# Which data structure is best for basic stacks and queues in C++?

Tags: c++, class, stack, queue, deque

I'm doing some newbie HackerRank problems in C++ and I'm finding that there seems to be several ways to solve this problem and I'm wondering which way is most widely used and/or most efficient. The problem requires creating a class that contains both `stack` and `queue` variables as well as `stack_push`/`stack_pop` and `queue_push`/`queue_pop` functions for them.

From what I've googled it seems I could either use `std::vector`, `std::stack` and `std::queue`, or `std::deque`, and maybe others.

I'm not sure how to determine which is best to use. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I implemented using `std::vector` for both and then using `std::stack` along with `std::queue` and I saw the same exact performance with both for a small-ish test case.
EDIT2:
 With a much bigger test case it looks like `std:stack`/`std:queue` outperforms `std:vector`. I'm guessing this is because of the FIFO queue half not being efficient with a vector, but I'll need to test this out more.

Comment: Always use `std::vector`.

Comment: always? why is that?

Comment: `std::stack` and `std::queue` are not containers per se, they take an underlying container usually `std::vector`.

Comment: @Jake: Well, as long as you have to ask, it's simply the easiest and best choice. Once you know how to appreciate that another data structure is better, you won't have to ask anymore.

Comment: @101010: And why is that a bad thing?

Comment: (That said, most hackerrank problems have small, bounded input sizes and usually don't require any dynamic containers at all.)

Comment: @FrankPuffer Didn't say that is a bad thing, just clearing things out ;)

Comment: So should I avoid using these higher level containers, and if so, why? edit: deleted incorrect statement

Comment: @KerrekSB: `std::vector` is fine for a stack. Pretty bad for a queue, unless you're going to use it as a circular queue and manage front and back indexes.

Comment: @KerrekSB, std::deque is preferrable in certain scenarios.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: @erip, nope. `std::deque` is good for queue.

Comment: On a side note, C++ problems on HackerRank are terrible. I've seen them,  they are simply bad.

Comment: @erip, would you be able to explain how `std::list` is better than `std::deque` for a queue?

Comment: Ok so I implemented the stack with a vector. What if I implement the queue with a vector also by using `vector.insert(vector.begin(), char)` and `vector.pop_back()` for the corresponding queue_push/queue_pop functions? Is there any disadvantage to using a vector also for the queue?

Comment: @erip, merging is not an operation which usually defined for queues.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm confused. you're saying I should essentially use std::queue to build a stack?

Comment: No, @LokiAstari is saying that you shouldn't build it, but just use which is already available. However, LIFO is a queue, not a stack. If you are building stack, you should use `std::stack`.

Comment: Using std::queue for a stack when there exists a std::stack seems incredibly confusing... I thought LIFO was a stack and FIFO was a queue??

Comment: This whole thread is getting confusing...

Comment: @erip, agreed. Let me sum it up. Do not build your own structures, use ones already available. Use `std::stack` for stack needs, `std::queue` for queue needs.

Comment: If you want LIFO use `std::stack` if you want FIFO `use std::queue`. Both are container wrappers. Use default values unless you can prove with timing that the default is not efficient enough.

Comment: @SergeyA Shall we clean up our comments?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Maybe, but I'd hazard a guess that for the OP's use, a vector will still be perfectly adequate, even for use as a queue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::stack` uses `std::deque` as the underlying container. So does `std::queue`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

From the referenced page

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

> Container -   The type of the underlying container to use to store the
>   elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of
>   SequenceContainer. Additionally, it must provide the following
>   functions with the usual semantics: back() push_back() pop_back() The
>   standard containers std::vector, std::deque and std::list satisfy
>   these requirements.

If the situation permits, I would use `std::stack` or `std::queue` without bothering about the underlying details. If I have to take more control, I would choose `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1):

The thumb rule is, first, identify all your requirements and then use the simplest data structure which meets all of them. Since you don't have a search requirement, the best will be to implement a C-style linked list. For the Stack, you need only one pointer to the front element, but for the Queue, you will have to maintain 2 pointers to keep track of the front element as well as the last element. This will probably be the fastest implementation.